# How to refresh Popup

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, statusbar

I am learning Swift and SwiftUI, and possibly plunging into the deep end by writing a StatusBar App, following a few tutorials.

Here is a stripped-down version of something which works. The aim is to be aware of the front most application, which I am simply displaying for the moment.

The code in the Content View does what I want the first time, but from there on, it doesn’t run again.

What do I need to do to get the Content View to refresh?

I am on XCode 11.7.

```swift
//  AppDelegate.swift
import SwiftUI

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var popover: NSPopover!
    var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let contentView = ContentView()
        self.popover = NSPopover()
        self.popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)

        self.statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: 18)
        if let statusBarButton = self.statusBarItem.button {
            statusBarButton.title = "☰"
            statusBarButton.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))
        }
    }
    
    @objc func togglePopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        let statusBarButton=self.statusBarItem.button!
        if self.popover.isShown {
            popover.performClose(sender)
        }
        else {
            self.popover.show(relativeTo: statusBarButton.bounds, of: statusBarButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
        }
    }

//  ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI
import AppKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let application=NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication
        let name=application?.localizedName ?? "Dunno"
        print("Got \(name)")
        return Text("Application: \(name)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application name in your `ContentView` is fixed after you instantiate it. So it won't react to action. Here is a solution:

`AppDelegate.swift`

```swift
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!

    var popover: NSPopover!
    var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!
    var applicationInfo = ApplicationInfo()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView(application: applicationInfo)
        self.popover = NSPopover()
        self.popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)

        self.statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: 18)
        if let statusBarButton = self.statusBarItem.button {
            statusBarButton.title = "☰"
            statusBarButton.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))
        }
    }
    
    @objc func togglePopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        let statusBarButton=self.statusBarItem.button!
        if self.popover.isShown {
            popover.performClose(sender)
        } else {
            applicationInfo.name = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication?.localizedName ?? "Dunno"
            self.popover.show(relativeTo: statusBarButton.bounds, of: statusBarButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
        }
    }
}
```

---

`ContentView.swift`:

```swift
class ApplicationInfo: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String
    init() {
        name = "Dunno"
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var application: ApplicationInfo
    var body: some View {
        return Text("Application: \(application.name)")
    }
}
```

The `View` and action are wired together by `ApplicationInfo`.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to include the full application information, and I can now move forward …